# Invalid value for prop `disabled` on <button> tag

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to get selected row count from the child component as a prop. I want to use that value to disable a button. This is how I am achieving it:
Parent Component:

```
const isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect = (selectedRowCount) => {
        console.log("selectedRow Count", selectedRowCount);
        setRowCount(selectedRowCount);
        if (selectedRowCount > 1) {
            console.log('true');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }


{
   icon: <EditIcon />,
   onClick: onClickEditActiveList,
   isDisabled: isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect
},

<IconButton flat secondary icon={ele.icon} isDisabled={ele.isDisabled} onClick={ele.onClick}/>
```

I have obtained selectedRowCount from the child component and using the value to decide if the button has to be enabled or disabled. The function has to return boolean value. But in doing so I get the following warning:

[image]

Child Component:

```
const getSelectedRowData = (event) => { 
        props.onselectedRows(event.api.getSelectedRows().length);
    }
```

The row selection event is being captured in child component and passed to parent using props.

I am guessing that its my use of the selectedRowCount that is causing this issue but I am not able to find an alternative solution. Please help

Comment: Can you share a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) show us how you are trying to disable a button?

Comment: Ok but when you use `isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect` on disabled property what do you call? `<button disabled={isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect}> my button </button>` ?

Comment: You're still missing how you actually try disabling a button. I suspect you are simply attaching the `isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect` function instead of invoking it with a row count.

Comment: Can you please elaborate invoking it with a row count ?

Comment: Could you show us `button` html please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following line assigns `isDisabled` to the *function* `isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect`:

```js
isDisabled: isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect
```

You need to call this function at some point.  One option is to call it in this definition:

```js
isDisabled: isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect()
```

Another option is to call it when using `isDisabled`:

```js
<IconButton flat secondary icon={ele.icon} isDisabled={ele.isDisabled()} onClick={ele.onClick}/>
```

Which you use depends on your full context (when you want the function to be evaluated, if it matters).
Do one, but not both.

It's also important not to call any `setState` functions while rendering the component; these can only be called in callbacks or `useEffect`s.  For example:

```js
const isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect = (selectedRowCount) => {
        console.log("selectedRow Count", selectedRowCount);
        // don't call setRowCount
        if (selectedRowCount > 1) {
            console.log('true');
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Neither option works. I get "Too many re-renders" error :(

Comment: Ah, that is because you're calling `setRowCount(selectedRowCount)`, but you can't call that directly from the function component. What are you trying to do? Why do you need to `setRowCount` to decide whether to disable the component? Could you show the code where `setRowCount` is defined?

Comment: I want to disable the edit button if there are more than two rows selected in ag-grid table. Hence, I am capturing the rowCount in isDisabledOnMultipleRowSelect function. The selectedRowCount is a prop value that I get from the child component. The event triggered is being captured in child component and passed as a prop to parent. Hope I was able to explain well.

Comment: Passing in `selectedRowCount` from the parent makes sense, but why are you calling `setRowCount`, which is presumably a `useState` set function? You can't do this, and you can just use the prop directly instead of setting a variable to it. I'll update the code above.

Comment: No, that didn't help either :( Still get that warning.